# how i can solve it? mysql 5.5 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near 'mysql dump --all-databases > dump.sql' at line 
1. for ubuntu server
```

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The command is mysqldump.

You have a space there, so you are effectively trying to run a mysql query dump, which is of course not valid.

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: mysqldump --all-databases > foo.sql

Please read what you entered into the terminal, and what I wrote.

Comment: @vidarlo: you maybe want to add your comment to your answer which would improve it.

Comment: please more clear to me.this problem.

Comment: I don't have any smaller spoons. The command you have to run is mysqldump. If you read what you are typing, you are typing mysql dump. There is a space. There should not be a space.

Comment: `mysql` and `mysqldump` are two different commands.  The one in your Question is `mysql`.   That command is being used incorrectly.  The command you want to use is `mysqldump`.  Copy and paste this to your terminal to get the output you are looking for: **`mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql`**.  It might not be obvious at a glance that there is a difference.  The difference is in the first word of the command.